# ERROR 1370 (42000) alter routine command denied to user

Tags: craft3, mysql, mamp

I am trying to upload my DB using MySQL Workbench but am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1370 (42000) at line 4534: alter routine command denied to user 'detectalocal'@'%' for routine 'detectalocal.checkLicensesExpiration'
```

How do I troubleshoot this? My root account has all of the correct permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your Craft install has some custom stored procedures in it.  I say custom because Craft doesn't use them by default and therefore doesn't require the necessary privileges to use them.

You'd need to make sure the MySQL user account Craft is running as and the one you're using to import the database backup has the 
[ALTER ROUTINE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter-routine) and [CREATE ROUTINE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-routine) privileges to properly use them.